# how to use mysqlfrm command?

Tags: mysql

When i'm trying to recover my table from `.frm` file using `mysqlfrm` I'm facing the below error. Please suggest a way to do it.

```
mysql> mysqlfrm --basedir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data" test2:ganesh.frm;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysq
frm --basedir="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data" test2:ganesh.frm' at
line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqlfrm` is a utility, not a SQL statement.

The mysql command line client is looking for a valid SQL statement.

The MySQL Utilities documentation includes an example of how to invoke the utility from an OS command prompt.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqlfrm.html